# parallox in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, branding

HI i wat to put an image in my sharepoint page in which when you go up and down the page is static I think it is named as parallax background something like this site http://oiecgroup.com/SitePages/index.html the section show in below image

[image]

Comment: I could not find a static image on the site

Answer (score 0):

Try it as below:

If you want it specifically on homepage, insert the below code in `script editor/content editor webpart`.

But if you want it for entire site collection, add it in the custom css file referred in masterpage or on the masterpage itself.

```
#s4-workspace
{
    background:url('../Style Library/Images/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

or as below:

```
body.ms-backgroundImage
{
  background: url('../Style Library/Images/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

As per your comments, you want it for a specific section. Try it as below:

1) Edit your page by clicking on gear icon in top right.

[image]

2) Click on Add webpart. After doing that, click on the Script editor webpart and then click OK as below:

[image]

3) I have selected Script editor webpart. Inside the webpart, add the below code snippet.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sitecollectionurl/siteassets/parallax.min.js"></script>

<style>
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
</style>

<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://sitecollectionurl/SiteAssets/Instant%20Intranet/Theme%20Two/images/rapidcircle.png"></div>
```

4) Once that is done, click on Save. Checkin and publish the page. And there you have parallax for a specific section as below:

[image]

You need to change the path to that of your site collection.

Comment: I donot want it on whole site I want it in special section I found the code in  http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ but donot know how to use it in sharepoint

Comment: @maria1368 - check the edited answer. You need to download the parallax js and upload it in your site collection. Once done, just follow the steps I have mentioned in Edit 2 section

Comment: thank you but I have a problem how could I choose the section I want this picture show because now it appear at top side of my site

Comment: I want it to be just in middle of page as the picture in my first page in http://oiecgroup.com/SitePages/index.html

Comment: You need to add some css to get it to work.